# Can a database table refer to more then one table without breaking any design principles

Tags: mysql, database

This is "what is the best practice" question.

I have 3 tables: orders, customer and address.

```
Order
------
ID
ADDRESS_ID


Customer
------
ID


Address
------
ID
CUSTOMER_ID
IS_HIDDEN
```

User can have multiple address and is free to edit them at any time. When user places an order I need to store a "snapshot" of his address at that time, associate it with the order and make it unavailable to the user. In other words, I want to duplicate address row which will be owned by Order table instead of Customer. This ownership needs to be somehow indicated (for example with IS_HIDDEN flag).

Is this correct approach that some data from address table is sometimes "owned" by a Customer table and sometimes by "Order"?.

The other solution would be replicating all columns from Address table in Order so the ownership will be explicit but I have bad feelings about duplication in schema.

Comment: I would rather use a OrderAddress table, that way the order can own the addresses. In my opinion that would be better since it clearly states ownership

Comment: Agree with @PeterHagström above. If you do decide to go with the is_hidden approach, I would suggest duplicating the address only when the user tries to edit an address that is being used by an existing order. So in most cases the Order and Customer would be referring to the same Adress row.

Comment: Agree with Peter, such an OrderAddress table would contain a snapshot of each order and its corresponding address at that specific point in time.

Comment: @PeterHagström: taking your advice does it mean Customers should have CustomerAddres table?

Comment: Well the naming is not critical but CustomerAddress is more explicit then just Address

Comment: I perhaps misunderstood you. What columns would you put into OrderAddress? Does it have the same structure as the address or it's just a link table?

Comment: The practice I've seen so far was mostly to save all the order info (including both shipping and billing addresses) directly in the `order` table. However, I somewhat like the idea of storing ALL the addresses in the `address` table and then just referring to them by id. This might aid avoiding redundancy with customers never changing their address and having both shipping and billing the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want a snapshot of the address *you should probably store the address in the **order***, not a separate table.

You would be making your queries and data unnecessarily complicated.

And with the implementation you are describing you would get duplication anyway.

**Example:**

> Customer Address = 1 street
>
> Customer places order the address is hidden in the table.
>
> Customer places another order with the same address.  The address is
>   saved and hidden in the table.

The final result would be:

```
Customer ID | Address  | Hidden  
    1       | 1 street |  false  
    1       | 1 street |  true  
    1       | 1 street |  true
```

Answer (score 1):

please use a link table (sometimes called an associative table) to link the address to the things it should link to.

"customer" and "order" are not part of an address - and should not be included in that table for proper normalization.

try something like

```
customer_address
------------------
customer_id
address_id
begin_dt
end_dt
type <- indicate physical location, mailing address etc.
```

similarly

```
order_address
---------------
order_id
address_id
type <- ship to, bill to - or others.
```